# Do I have to do something additional in react and express If I already install my SSL certificate in the cpanel?

Tags: reactjs, express, ssl-certificate, cpanel, godaddy-api

When I browse the page with the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mypage\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mypage.com/$1 [R,L]
```

My page is redirected to a /index.html empty page. With out the htaccess code the http and https routes works properly but the initial page is always http.

My express and react app doesn´t have any configuration related to SSL and my hosting provider is godaddy. Is there some additional steps to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this code `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mypage.com/$1 [R,L]` delete `$1`.